# Evernote -3000 error, status code 201, stopping users from authenticating

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, evernote, error-code

This error only seems to happen to some users, and I'm unsure how many. The ones who do receive it, receive it continually. I have the method:

```
authenticateWithViewController:completionHandler:
```

And in the completion handler, they receive the following error:

```
Error Domain=com.evernote.sdk Code=-3000 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.evernote.sdk error -3000.)" UserInfo=0x1d8a2ae0 {statusCode=401}
```

Any way that I can find out what this error means and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you follow all steps when integrating the SDK including [modifying your plist file](https://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-ios#modify-your-applications-main-plist-file) and [AppDelegate](https://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-ios#modify-your-appdelegate)

Answer (score 0):

Yes i have also getting this error.
After setting  **consumer key in plist URL scheme** it is running fine.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is described by this post:

https://discussion.evernote.com/topic/40618-ios-cant-auth-via-app-but-can-through-website/?locale=en

Basically in the delegate if you have also dropbox api defined you need to combine the requests in the method:  (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url

Hope it helps.

dom